# Managing SQL server from Mac Terminal

Tags: sql-server, macos

How can I manage SQL server from a Mac terminal? Is there any tools Out there that will let me do it?

Comment: local or remote? what sql server? mysql? postgres???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-sqlserver#mac)?  This is available for Windows & OSX

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're wanting to get to the MS SQLServer management console and what you have is a Mac, and the Mac has a network connection that will allow the RDP TCP protocol to the Windows server running SQLServer, you probably want to install the [Remote Desktop Client](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/networking_security/remotedesktopconnectionclient.html) on your Mac. That may not allow you to log in and manage SQL Server, though. The Windows server may have to be configured to allow remote logins (via RDP). There may also be permissions lacking for running the SQLServer management console as a remote user. Since I've successfully managed to stop managing SQLServer (and Windoze servers), I can't check to see what permissions should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but a colleague recommended www.razorsql.com - I will try it shortly, because it does other RDMS platforms too.

I bought a Mac Book Pro a couple of months ago, and eagerly downloaded Microsoft's RDP for the Mac. Maybe it's just me, but it's a really unsatisfactory experience: small screen, funny colours. I think I'll next try running a Windows box on VMWare Fusion, and RDP in from that.

Comment: @IDWMaster - Please save those comments for Engadget.